PayPal Transaction Search API not including transaction_note property
The API described at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/ is no longer returning "transaction_note", for transactions that definitely have notes, and which returned notes previously.
Our code hasn't changed and I can also look at the raw json to see that the transaction_note value is simply no longer there, including for older transactions that had their value returned before.
If I load the TXT log of the associated mass pay, I can see the note we provided.
The only time that the value is being returned in the API is when it's a Paypal-assigned note, for example "Mass Pay Reversal".
It was working as of at least March of this year.

Are you asking for any specific fields, or are you letting it return just the default, transaction_info? Maybe they changed the definition of the latter.

@C3roe,
I'm letting it return the default, transaction_info. Loos like you can only request specific types of fields, not specific fields themselves (eg transaction_note). But the documentation doesn't indicate any changes, and the notes are present when they're PayPal-assigned.
The note values are also blank when I use the Reports feature in the dashboard but it's been that way for a while, which is why we switched to API about three years ago.
